# How to lowercase first letter of each new line in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
myString = "I Am New To Python,    
            Trying to learn Different things.    
            Need your help in this Case."
```

I want like this:

```
myString2 = "i Am New To Python,
             trying to learn Different things.
             need your help in this Case."
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, mystring2 is missing a comma at the end of the first line. Is that correct or is that a typing mistake?

Comment: Hi Francis, yes that was a typo. I have edited it now. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: That's not a valid string declaration in Python.  It needs to be triple-quoted to span more than one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression substitution matching the first character in a line and replaced with its lower-case version is pretty straightforward:

```
import re

myString = '''I Am New To Python,    
              Trying to learn Different things.    
              Need your help in this Case.'''

print(re.sub(r'^(\s*.)',lambda m: m.group(1).lower(),myString,flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Output:

```
i Am New To Python,    
trying to learn Different things.    
need your help in this Case.
```

Note you need to triple-quote your string to be valid.  I included the leading white space in the replacement so the result would remove it.  Use `r'^\s*(.)'` to leave it in.

The replacement is an anonymous function that receives the match object of the regular expression.

Comment: I am working on a large dataset, this regex is doing my task in lesser time. Thanks for the input @Mark Tolonen

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension you can do like,

```
myString = '''I Am New To Python,    
            Trying to learn Different things.    
            Need your help in this Case.'''

modified_string = '\n'.join([i.strip()[0].lower()+i.strip()[1:] for i in myString.split('\n')])
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: I'm quite rusty on my list comprehension, so I'm going to try your solution out @SmashGuy. Nice one.

Comment: I too found it difficult in beginning times. But once i learn it, i find it so interesting. hope you too feel the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know list comprehension yet, this might be an easier one to understand for beginners.

```
myString = """I Am New To Python,
Trying to learn Different things.
Need your help in this Case."""
mystring1=myString.splitlines()
mystring2=""
for x in mystring1:
    mystring2 = mystring2 + x[0].lower() + x[1:] +"\n"
print(mystring2)
```

Comment: You can test out Python code using an online code test like this one
http://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler